# Retrieve kotlin annotations from java class

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have an interface which has annotation:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Foo()

interface Bah {
    @Foo val prop: String
}
```

I'm implementing a jackson contextual deserializer, and I need to pick up this annotation from the methods in the interface.

```
   override fun createContextual(ctxt: DeserializationContext, property: BeanProperty?): JsonDeserializer<*> {
        val clzz = ctxt.contextualType.rawClass as Class<T>
        for (method in clzz.methods) {
            val anns = method.getAnnotationsByType(Foo::class.java)
```

`ctxt.contextualType` is a JavaType. I obtain clzz from it, which yields me a class of type Bah (i.e. the interface). I can iterate the methods, which include "prop"; however, prop has no annotations.

It DOES work if I modify the annotation site to look like this:

```
interface Bah {
    val prop: String
        @Foo() get
```

However, that's ugly. How can I modify things so that I can retrieve from the interface property directly?

Thanks

Comment: well... if `val prop: String @Foo() get` works (so basically you added `AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER`?), then you could also just use `@get:Foo val prop : String` ... still the same "problem"... but maybe you like that more?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. As [the documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), annotations targeting a property are not visible from Java (because Java does not have the concept of properties).

Comment: OK - so then what should it be?